# Update title dynamically on Apexcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, apexcharts

I am using Updateseries to update x and y axis. How can i update title?

```
$.getJSON('chartData.php', {
    devicename: feature.get('id')
}, (response) => {
    chart.updateSeries([{
        data: response
    }])

    let chart = new ApexCharts(document.getElementById("chart"), options)
    chart.updateOptions({
    title: 'Water Consumption per day on December 2019 for '
  })  

 });
```

Comment: Ok I used: `$(".apexcharts-title-text").text("lel")`

Comment: The above method is not recommended as it will be wiped off on the next render. Try resizing your browser and you'll see it goes back to original. Please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `updateOptions` method of ApexCharts to update any other configuration.

`updateSeries` only deals with data of the chart, while `updateOptions` allows changing the configuration of the chart dynamically

```js
var chart = new ApexCharts(el, options);

chart.updateOptions({
  title: {
    text: 'new title'
  }
})
```

Docs for updateOptions - https://apexcharts.com/docs/methods/#updateOptions

Comment: see my updated question, i get error on updateseries: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'chart' before initialization`

Comment: You cannot call `updateSeries` before the chart is rendered. Move down the `updateSeries` line below `new ApexCharts`

Comment: Now i get: `apexcharts:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined`

Comment: You are not calling the `render` method before updating the series. Please refer the docs - https://apexcharts.com/docs/creating-first-javascript-chart/
After you get the chart rendered, you can call any other methods.

Comment: The chart is already rendered when the page loads. When i want to update (e.g. retrieve data via ajax) i need to render it again?

Comment: No, you don't need to call `render` more than once. Please create a codepen demo so we can take a closer look.

Comment: I follow this nice example: https://apexcharts.com/docs/update-charts-from-json-api-ajax/. I also want to update the title with the data.

Comment: Please take a look, very basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/btowg90k/

Answer (score 0):

this code can update the title in the chart.

```
*ApexCharts.exec('id', "updateOptions", {*
        title:{
            text:title1
        }
    });
```

Comment: To add value to your answer consider adding a short explanation on what this code does.